# expected unqualified-id error, most likely cause?

Tags: c++

I'm getting the following error:

ListIterator.cpp:6: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘using’
make: *** [ListIterator.o] Error 1

when compiling a linked list program. Any ideas what the most likely cause could be? It should not be a scope-based problem in the IntNode.h/.cpp files.

```
// ListIterator.h

#include "IntNode.h"
//#include "nullptr.cpp"

class ListIterator {
    private:
        IntNode* pointer;
    public:
        ListIterator( IntNode* );

    int& operator*();

    ListIterator& operator++();

    bool operator!=( ListIterator liter );

}



// ListIterator.cpp

#include "ListIterator.h"
//#include "nullptr.cpp"

using namespace std;

    ListIterator :: ListIterator( IntNode* init = nullptr ) : pointer( init ) {};

    int& ListIterator :: operator*() {
        return pointer -> getInt();
    };

    ListIterator& ListIterator :: operator++() {
        pointer = pointer -> getNext();
    };

    bool ListIterator :: operator!=( ListIterator liter ) {
        return pointer != liter.pointer;
    };
```

Comment: You forgot a semicolon after class definition.

Comment: And you don't need the semicolons after the function definitions in the source file. They don't hurt, but they don't do anything either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// ListIterator.h

#include "IntNode.h"
//#include "nullptr.cpp"

class ListIterator {
    private:
        IntNode* pointer;
    public:
        ListIterator( IntNode* );

    int& operator*();

    ListIterator& operator++();

    bool operator!=( ListIterator liter );

};
```

you forgot ";" at the end

Comment: @staxas btw, please accept the answer by pressing the "v" below the answer's votes